# find intersection between vectors holding the peaks of two signals

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two signals and I calculated the local peaks of each signal and saved them in two different vectors for amplitude and another two for timing. I need to get the intersection between peaks. Each peak has a value and a time so I am trying to extract the peaks which has nearly the same amplitude at nearly the same time .. Any help??

My Code:

```
    [svalue1,stime1] = findpeaks(O1);
    [svalue2,stime2] = findpeaks(O2);
    %note that the peaks count is different in each signal
    % This is my try but it is not working
    x = length(intersect(ceil(svalue1),ceil(svalue2)))/min(length(svalue1),length(svalue2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding what you want to determine those values in `svalue1` and `svalue2` that are similar to each other, and what's more important is that they are **unequal** in length.

What you can do is compare every value in `svalue1` with every value in `svalue2` and if the difference between a value in `svalue1` and a value in `svalue2` is less than a certain amount, then we would classify these two elements to be the same.

This can be achieved by [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with the `@minus` function and eliminating any sign changes with `abs`.  After, we can determine the locations where the values are below a certain amount.

Something like this:

```
tol = 0.5; %// Adjust if necessary
A = abs(bsxfun(@minus, svalue1(:), svalue2(:).')) <= tol;
[row,col] = find(A);
out = [row,col];
```

`tol` is the tolerance that we would use to define whether two values are close together.  I chose this to be 0.5, but adjust this for your application.  `out` is a 2D matrix that tells you which value in `svalue1` was closest to `svalue2`.  Rather than giving a verbose explanation, let's just show you an example of this working and we can explain along the way.

---

Let's try this on an example:

```
>> svalue1 = [0 0.1 1 2.2 3];
>> svalue2 = [0.1 0.2 2 3 4];
```

Running the above code, we get:

```
>> out

ans =

     1     1
     2     1
     1     2
     2     2
     4     3
     5     4
```

Now this makes sense.  Each row tells you which value in `svalue1` is close to `svalue2`.  For example, the first row says that the first value in `svalue1`, or 0 is close to the second value in `svalue2` or 0.1.  The next row says that the second value of `svalue1`, or 0.2, is close to the first value of `svalue2`, or 0.

Obviously, this operation includes non-unique values.  For example, the row with `[1 2]` and `[2 1]` are the same.  I'm assuming this isn't a problem, so we'll leave that alone.

---

Now what I didn't cover is whether the peaks also happen within the same time value.  This can be done by performing another `bsxfun` operation on the time vector values of `stime1` and `stime2` much like we did with `svalue1` and `svalue2`, and performing a logical AND operation between the two matrices.  Should the peaks be the same in **both** amplitude and time, then the result follows.... so something like this:

```
tol_amplitude = 5; %// Adjust if necessary
tol_time = 0.5;
A = abs(bsxfun(@minus, svalue1(:), svalue2(:).')) <= tol_amplitude;
Atime = abs(bsxfun(@minus, stime1(:), stime2(:).')) <= tol_time;
Afinal = A & Atime;
[row,col] = find(Afinal);
out = [row,col];
```

You'll notice that we have two thresholds for the time and the amplitudes.  Adjust both if necessary.  `out` will contain the results like we saw earlier, but these will give you those indices that are close in **both** time and amplitude.  If you want to see what those are, you can do something like this:

```
peaks = [svalue1(out(:,1)) svalue2(out(:,2))];
times = [stime1(out(:,1)) stime2(out(:,2))];
```

`peaks` and `times` will give you what the corresponding peaks and times were that would be considered as "close" between the two signals.  The first column denotes the peaks and times for the first signal and the second column is for the peaks and times for the second signal.  The difference between columns should be less than their prescribed thresholds.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng, but the time is important. so for example I have a peak at time 10 with amplitude 100 and in the other vector I have a peak at time 10.1 with amplitude 95 .. this means that there is intersection as the time and the amplitude is nearly the same.

Comment: @SMH - No problem.  I've updated my post.  Have a look.

Comment: @SMH - I made further changes.  Noticed a flaw in my logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot and is out = [row,col] ??

Comment: and I tried it, there is an error says that A and Atime don't have the same size .. and I found that they don't have the same size and we can't AND them

Comment: @SMH Are you sure??? That doesn't make any sense.  If `svalue1` and `stime1` are the same length, and `svalue2` and `stime2` are the same length, then the above should work.  `bsxfun` should give you a `M x N` matrix where `M` is the length of `svalue1/stime1` and `N` is the length of `svalue2/stime2`.

Comment: The difference between their size is 3

Comment: @SMH The first and second outputs of `findpeaks` should share the same size.  The first output gives you the peaks and the second output gives you the time index at each of those peaks.  Having them to be different lengths makes no sense whatsoever.  You are probably modifying them unintentionally somewhere.

Comment: @SMH Specifically, `numel(svalue1) == numel(stime1)`.  Also, `numel(svalue2) == numel(stime2)`.  If this is **not** the case, then you are doing something to these values before you run my code - the unequal lengths is not due to my code.

Comment: you are right, I checked my code and fixed it. Many Thanks

Comment: @SMH - No problem :) I'm glad we figured it out!